# Do the seminorms $|\int_{\frac{1}{n-1}}^\frac{1}{n} f(x) dx|$ separate points?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let's define family of seminorms:

$$p_n(f)  = |\int_{\frac{1}{n+1}}^\frac{1}{n} f(x) dx|$$

on $C([0, 1])$

I want to check whether this norm family of seminorms separates points. i.e. I have to check:

$$(p_n(f) = 0 )\Rightarrow f = 0$$

**My work so far**

$$p_k(f) = |\int_{\frac{1}{k+1}}^{\frac{1}{k}} f(x) dx| = 0 \Rightarrow \int_{\frac{1}{k+1}}^{\frac{1}{k}} f(x) dx = 0$$

Now I wanted to take function defined in the following way:

[image]

This function completely fits our example - area under the curve on the interval $[\frac{1}{k+1}, \frac{1}{k}]$ is $0$.

But I realized that it's different function for different $k$ (definition of this function depends on k).

I tried to find another function that is $k -$ independent however I wasn't able to.

I was also trying to prove that it has to be separable (that $f \equiv 0$) but also I end up with nothing. Could you please give me hint what's the direction I should follow?

Comment: Is $n \ge 2$ or should the lower bound of the integral be $\frac{1}{n+1} < \frac{1}{n}$? And to be clear: are you trying to prove that if $p_n(f) = 0$ *for all n*, then $f = 0$?

Comment: That's exactly what I want to prove

Comment: Sory for the mistake, I already improved the question - It should make more sense now

Comment: What is your basic space? Are you considering only continuous functions?

Comment: Yup, I should have wrote that. My space is $C([0, 1])$, you can find this information now also in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Will adjust the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By a similar construction you can write down a continuous function $f_n$ on $[\frac 1 {n+1}, \frac  1n]$ which vanishes at the end points and has integral $0$ with $ \sup |f_n(x)|=\frac 1 n$. Now just define $f(x)=f_n(x)$ when $x \in (\frac 1 {n+1}, \frac 1n]$, $n=1,2,...$ and $f(0)=0$ and that defines your function on the whole of $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! It's not a problem that definition of your $f$ depends on $n$? If not, then why my example which I showed in my question is bad? ;))

Comment: My function does not depend on $n$. It is one fixed function. I am using the fact that the intervals $(\frac 1 {n+1}, \frac 1n]$ form  a partition of the inetrval $(0,1]$ and I am defining $f$ separately in these intervals so that the values at the end points maintain continuity. Your function depends on $n$ but mine does not.  @Lucian

Comment: Okay, I was kinda confused with the notation. I thought that you are defining seperate function for seperate $n$ but your construction solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Define
$$
f(x) =\begin{cases} 0 & \text{ if } x\le 1/2\\
\sin(4\pi x) & \text{ if } x> 1/2.
\end{cases}
$$
Then $p_n(f)=0$ for all $n$. There is no need to build a function $f$ that is non-zero on all these subintervals.